# C++ How to identify the type of a variable

Tags: c++, types

Given a variable taken from a vector, is there a way to identify the type.

Note that I already know the type of member and can specify it in the call to a template. This is a specific vector that allows a push_back() of particular types of variables.

For example, we have a class that allows a vector operation.

```
auto data = member().back(); // gets the last entry in the member vector
```

Using a template, I want to create a new entry of the type

```
dataType newdata;
member().push_back(newdata)
```

Is there a way of identifying what dataType is, given the result of the back() operation? If there is, I can create a Template, and retrieve the type by passing in the member indicator.

If not, I would have to pass in the type specifically in order to define

```
::base::dataArea newdata;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: `member().resize(member().size()+1)`.

You cannot reason about unknown datatypes in general, so there is very little what you can do with them. You can't blindly assume they have a member `.foo()` for instance. You might reasonably assume that the type has a default, copy and/or move constructor, and then you often don't need to spell out the type either - as shown in the `.resize()` call.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use `typename std::remove_reference<decltype( member().back() )>::type` if you really want to be clever. But instead you should use `typename V::value_type`, where `V` is the type of the vector accessed via `member`. See e.g. the [docs at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector): it's often a good idea to consult the relevant documentation.

Comment: Clearly `std::remove_reference<decltype(member.back())::type` is the correct solution then :)

Comment: I do not need to get the type of member, I want to get the type of what is being stored in the Member vector so that I can create a new entry to push_back ont the vector. I will try to clarify the question.

Comment: @sabbahillel: the question is OK.

Comment: Thanks, however, reading the documentation page, I am not sure how to use it to refer to the type. How do I take the type created and actually use it?

Comment: Just declare the new type. For example, if `member` is of type `std::vector<int>`, the following would be valid

`std::remove_reference<decltype(member.back())>::type newInt = 5;`

`newInt` is of type `int`